# How did Richard Feynman arrive at the hamiltonian equation for an electron propagating in a crystal lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

In Richard Feynman's lectures on Physics Vol III, Chapter 13-1, he described the state of an electron in a crystal lattice to be approximated by the linear combination of the orthogonal atom orbitals:

$$|\phi\rangle\hspace{1mm} = \sum_{n} |n\rangle\langle n|\phi\rangle\hspace{1mm} = \sum_{n} C_{n} |n\rangle$$

Where $|n\rangle$ is the state of the electon being at the $n^{\text{th}}$ atom.
By treating the electron as a wave with amplitude $iA/\hbar$, he proposes that the partial hamiltonian equation be:

$$i\hbar \frac{dC_{n}(t)}{dt} = E_{0}C_{n}(t) - AC_{n+1}(t) - AC_{n-1}(t)$$

where $E_{0}$ is the energy the electron would have if it couldn't leak away from one of the atoms.

How did Feynman arrive at this proposal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially tight binding model, our hamiltonian elements are
$$\langle n|H|n\rangle=E_0$$
this is the energy to create an electron sitting at $n$.

$$\langle n+1|H|n\rangle=-\Delta$$
this is amplitude to hop  next site.
$$\langle n-1|H|n\rangle=-\Delta$$
this is amplitude to hop  to previous site.
Thus our partial Hamiltonian would look like 
$$H=-\Delta|n+1\rangle \langle n|+E_0 |n\rangle \langle n|-\Delta|n-1\rangle \langle n|$$
Now  we have
$$H|\phi,t\rangle= [E_{0}C_{n}(t) - \Delta C_{n+1}(t) - \Delta C_{n-1}(t)]|n\rangle$$
and LHS would be 
$$\frac{i\hbar\partial}{\partial t}|\phi,t\rangle=\sum_{n} \dot{C}_{n} 
|n\rangle$$
Thus if  we equate
$$\langle n|\frac{i\hbar\partial}{\partial t}|\phi,t\rangle=\langle n|H|\phi,t\rangle$$

we would arrive
$$i\hbar \frac{dC_{n}(t)}{dt} = E_{0}C_{n}(t) - \Delta C_{n+1}(t) - \Delta C_{n-1}(t)$$